# Diagonal line of table is out of margin using `diagbox` and `booktabs`

Tags: tables, formatting, typography

I'm using the `diagbox` package to create a table with diagonal line.

The code is

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{diagbox} 

\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lllll@{}}
        \toprule
        \diagbox{Column1}{Column2} & A & BB & CC & SS \\ \midrule
        AAA & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 \\
        BBB & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Test table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You will get a result looking like this:

[image]

See? The diagonal line is out of the table. How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many people would suggest you to use `booktabs` in the spirit of `booktabs`. And the result is probably much better (as least, it's my opinion).

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lllll@{}}
        \toprule
                  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Column2} \\ \cmidrule{2-5}
        Column1   & A & BB & CC & SS \\ \midrule
        AAA & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 \\
        BBB & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Test table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: How do I accept two answers at the same time? :)

Comment: I think it's not possible. You accept the best one (but I think you can change later if an ever best answer appears).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the result with the environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (≥ 4.0 2020-05-08) which provides a command `diagbox`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{@{}wl{2.8cm}LLLL@{}}
        \toprule
        \diagbox{Column1}{Column2} & A & BB & CC & SS \\ \midrule
        AAA & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 \\
        BBB & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}
    \caption{Test table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thanks, it's a solution, but doesn't answer why `diagbox` package fail?

Comment: and is `nicematrix` in TexLive 2012?

Comment: I think that `diagbox` has not been designed to be compatible with `booktabs`. There are other similar situations: `booktabs` is not compatible with `colortbl`...).

Comment: Hum... `nicematrix` is not at all in TeXLive 2012. I have begun writting `nicematrix` in 2018.

Comment: Oh no, the journal submission system is using TexLive 2012, I think.

Comment: Since version 5.0 of `nicematrix`, one must write `{@{}wl{2.8cm}llll@{}}` instead of `{@{}wl{2.8cm}LLLL@{}} `in the preamble of `{NiceTabular}` (but there is an option for backward compatibility).